# Why doesn't font lock work in the minibuffer?

Tags: font-lock, minibuffer

If you invoke `M-x eval-expression` then you can evaluate elisp expressions there, but there is no syntax highlight.

If I turn on `emacs-lisp-mode` in the `eval-expression` prompt then the major mode is switched to emacs-lisp, but the typed expression is still not highlighted.

Why is that? Why doesn't font lock work in the minibuffer?

Answer (score 2):

A guess is that the basic functions that read minibuffer input are defined in C, and they just don't allow/account for that.  (They're also old - predating even font-lock.  But that's not necessarily a/the reason they don't support font-lock.)

FWIW, there's a `FIXME` comment in the code defining `read--expression`, which asks whether it should turn on `emacs-lisp-mode`.

```lisp
(defun read--expression (prompt &optional initial-contents)
  (let ((minibuffer-completing-symbol t))
    (minibuffer-with-setup-hook
        (lambda ()
          ;; FIXME: call emacs-lisp-mode?
          (add-function :before-until (local 'eldoc-documentation-function)
                        #'elisp-eldoc-documentation-function)
          (eldoc-mode 1)
          (add-hook 'completion-at-point-functions
                    #'elisp-completion-at-point nil t)
          (run-hooks 'eval-expression-minibuffer-setup-hook))
      (read-from-minibuffer prompt initial-contents
                            read-expression-map t
                            'read-expression-history))))
```

But as you've discovered, turning on `emacs-lisp-mode` there won't support font-lock. And neither will explicitly turning on `font-lock-mode`.